# Unable to kill Oozie job

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, bigdata

I have created an Oozie job that triggers a hive script when executed. The workflow I created had some error due to which the Job is getting stuck in Prep mode. However, when I try to kill the job from command line using oozie job -oozie http://<*oozie-server*>:11000/oozie/ -kill 0000032-160617142637089-oozie-oozi-W, the job is not getting killed. Please find the screenshot for the job info as seen on the oozie console
[image]

The audit log for the above job. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your ports once.Check your service is up on port 8032.

[Refer this post](http://bhuvnesh2703-bigdata.blogspot.in/2015/05/oozie-hive-action-fails-with.html) for hive action stuck in prep state

Comment: This should have been a comment.